# In ruby on rails, how do you decode a content-transfer-encoding base64 Mail object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, base64, actionmailer, decode

I am working on ruby on rails ActionMailer. What I have done is that I had a background process polling my gmail account and I retrieve mails with 'RFC822' protocol. I then send these mails to a receive method inside my ActionMailer class.

While I can successfully process almost all of the incoming mails, sometimes I do encounter international mails, which have accent marks in english characters. When displaying the bodies of these mails to STDOUT, they appear to be some random characters as follow because I think the decoding is wrong...

This is the body of the mail object when I print it on the screen:

```
"PGh0bWw+PGhlYWQ+PG1ldGEgaHR0cC1lcXVpdj0iQ29udGVudC1MYW5ndWFnZSIgY29udGVudD0i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="
```

These international mails have Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64 as opposed to 7bit. So what do I need to do so that I can correctly decode the email? I have tried things like Base64.decode64, but it complains that there is no unpack method defined.

I have been working on this for couple hours with no luck. Could anyone please help me?

Thank you

Comment: Propably you figured it out till that time. Im looking for my answer about Base64 in ruby. My problem is that when there is content-transfer-encoding Base64 encoding should add new line every 76 characters, not 60 characters(default). So maybe you are decoding with newline every 60 chars instead of 76.

Answer (score 3):

At least nowadays ActionMailer is able to correctly decode those emails.
This should work:

```
message = Mail.new(encoded_body)
message.html_part.body.decoded
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the parameter you provide to `Base64.decode` is not a string. (Because `decode` falls back to `String.unpack`)

From [ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/base64/rdoc/classes/Base64.html#M000004):

```
def decode64(str)
  str.unpack("m").first
end
```